# No module named 'google.api_core.client_options' while importing firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Firestore with Python . I have successfully installed the `google-cloud-firestore`. But when I am trying to import the library using `from google.cloud import firestore` . It is throwing me the error

```
No module named 'google.api_core.client_options'
```

Note: I am not using the virtualenv
Is there any way i can resolve this

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading the [google-api-core library](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-core/):

```
/path/to/pip install --upgrade google-api-core
```

Comment: I am stilling getting this error even after successful installation.

Comment: Updated answer based on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8781

Comment: any news on this? I've the same issue